# Round corners showing white borders in IE8

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, css

I am using jQuery round corner plugin and border-radius.htc for round corners. It is working perfectly in al browsers othern than IE 8. It is showing some unwanted white borders. I am attaching the screen shot. It will be very much helpful if I get some tips for removing this.

Please check the screenshot here:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/gonline.png/

Answer (score 0):

**try background:transparent


If it doesn't work, post the code**

Comment: it is already added. I dont have that much code. it is only calling $('#elementid').corner() function. Please check the live site here http://bit.ly/H1hAZE